# Importing Maps.jar in eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

I am unable to find and import jar file of Google maps for android.

How to import Google Maps API maps.jar file in Eclipse.?

Please Help,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all update your SDK->Google Play Services and then

Find this Path in your Computer :

```
...\android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-17\libs\maps.jar
```

add this jar using `Add External Jar`...

I have solved my problem from above solution..

Thank you...

Comment: Try This : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You should download Google Apis in Eclipse (Android SDK manager). Compile using any Google Apis, and you will have the packages like google maps included already.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through this tutorial

[Android working with Google Maps V2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: [Google map V1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/) Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated. you provided tutorial is a tutorial of GoogleMapV1.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Best Tutorial, Try it

Comment: @baloo - i have edited your answer